# NLog writes to C:\ (root folder)

Tags: nlog

I have a web site with web.config where I have registered NLog.

```
  <nlog>
    <targets>
      <target name="MasterLogFile" type="File" fileName="${specialfolder:folder=LocalApplicationData}/CEDLogs/Master.Log.txt" 
                            layout="${longdate} ${message} ${exception:format=tostring}"/>
    </targets>
    <rules>
      <logger name="*" minlevel="Info" writeTo="MasterLogFile" />
    </rules>
  </nlog>
```

This is my button onclick handler on aspx page:

```
    protected void btnWriteLog_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Logger NLogger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
        NLogger.Info("Test message");
    }
```

I expected to see my text log file in app_pool_user\AppData\Local\CEDLogs, but instead I noticed it in c:\CEDLogs. Why does it happen to me ?

Thanks,

Slava

Comment: Could you log what `${specialfolder:folder=LocalApplicationData}` returns ? it would seem that that value is either empty or undefined.

Comment: yes, it is empty for some reason, maybe because this is a web app, but still  it runs under an account